# Conditionally changing the colour of a histogram in ggplot, and not displaying both bar outlines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, histogram

I would like to change the colour of a part of a histogram, both the fill and outline, but am having some difficulties. Copy the code below for an example:

```
require(ggplot2)

#make data
rand <- sample(1:500, 1200, replace=T)
dat <- data.frame(val=c(rand), name=c(rep("A",400),rep("B",400),rep("C",400)))
dat$cond <- ifelse(dat$val < 100 & dat$name=="B", "remove", dat$name)

# plot 3 histograms (A, B, C). Colour each histogram differently and colour data <100 in B differently 
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=val,colour=cond, fill=cond)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol=1)
```

[First attempt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52asg.png)

The problem here is the purple lines above all the green bars, is there any way to remove them?

I also tried a different method of changing the colour. See below:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=val,colour=name, fill=name)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4, data=subset(dat, name %in% c("A","C"))) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4, data=subset(dat, val<100 & name=="B"), fill="grey", colour="grey") +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4, data=subset(dat, val>=100 & name=="B")) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol=1)
```

[Second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPC6b.png)

So this fixes the lines on top of the bars, but I now have a green line below the grey bars. This is a result of the green bars being added to the plot after the grey bars. I can reverse the order but that makes a grey bar beneath the green bars. Is there any way to have both a grey line beneath the grey bars, and a green line beneath the green bars?

I apologise for the nit-picky nature of this question, but I'm making an image for publication so I want it to look perfect!

Comment: Draw twice, one without line and one without fill, you and manage the layer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, the solution was adding `drop=TRUE` to `geom_histogram` to drop bins with zero counts. This then removes prevents the overlaying of the outline.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=val,colour=name, fill=name)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4, data=subset(dat, name %in% c("A","C"))) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4, data=subset(dat, val<100 & name=="B"), fill="grey", colour="grey") +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4, data=subset(dat, val>=100 & name=="B"), drop=T) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply remove the edges of the bars?

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=val, fill=cond)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.4) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol=1)
```